# Rigging skirt with hook modifier

Tags: rigging, hook-modifier

I rigged a skirt to a model using automatic wights and it works quite well, but when the character is sitting the skirt doesn't "fall" on the the legs.

[image]

I tried fixing it by using a hook modifier. In the resting position it works and I can control the skirt using the circle that I hooked it to.

[image]
[image]

Now I wanted to combine the two solutions by parenting the circle to the armature. But as you can see this doesn't work

[image]

I also tried to use a bone instead of an object for the target of the hook. But this had the same effect.

[image]

Form experimenting it looks like the hook modifier uses the translation and rotation relative to translation and rotation when it was created. When I told the hook modifier to use the bone as target, while the character was sitting, it worked, but then it broke in the resting position.

So, my question is how can I tell the hook that it should use the translation and rotation relative to a bone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the scenario hook modifier was intended for.

You can try this setup, instead:

- skirt is child of hip, and has a copy rot bone constraint targeting thigh.l influence 1.0, followed by a copy rot bone constraint targeting thigh.r with influence 0.5
- DEF_skirt is child of skirt

Set skirt bone not deforming, move it to a hidden layer and assign some weight to DEF_skirt, expecially the center zone of the skirt.

Animate the DEF_skirt bone to control the borders.

[image]